Azure Logic App - Update o365 profile image
I am starting out with Logic Apps and having trouble passing an image to a HTTP PUT to update a users image.  Hoping I have missed the obvious.
I get the image from a Sharepoint list that our HR upload.  I then just want to post to the users o365 account but getting an error "Write requests (excluding DELETE) must contain the Content-Type header declaration."

Then using HTTP to update image.  Thinking the issue may be with the 'File Content' not being the right type and I need to convert to binary or something.


What is the type of file?

The file type is JPG

I provided the answer below with it @Corey, It will work

To put profile picture use below design:
Firstly get the file content :

Then use PUT method and below rest api:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/bojja@bb.com/photo/$value

Give Authorization and Content type:
Bearer token. You need get the access token and it should have all the permissions to change the picture

To change to binary :
binary(body('Get_file_content_using_path'))

Place the above expression in Expression section:

Or simply paste this @{binary(body('Get_file_content_using_path'))} in body :

Output:

For generating access token using client credential flow refer this SO-Thread, make sure to grant User.ReadWrite.All  of application permission type.

Thank you.  Knew it should be an easy fix.

Glad it worked for you @Corey
